Proving an absolute value inequality
I've come across the following problem: let $a,b$ and $c$ be positive real numbers such that: $$|a-b|\lt c\lt a+b$$
The desired result is to find that $$\left|\frac{1}{a+c}-\frac{1}{b+c}\right|\lt \frac{1}{a+b}\lt \frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{b+c}$$
I could show that $\left|\frac{1}{a+c}-\frac{1}{b+c}\right|\lt a+b$ like this: we know that $a+b\gt|a-b|$ which means that $\frac{a+b}{(a+c)(b+c)}\gt \frac{|a-b|}{(a+c)(b+c)}$,in other words, $\frac{a+b}{(a+c)(b+c)}\gt |\frac{a-b}{(a+c)(b+c)}|$ and we know that $\frac{a+b}{(a+c)(b+c)}\lt a+b$, hence $a+b\gt|\frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{b+c}|$, also I could show that $|\frac{1}{a+c}-\frac{1}{b+c}|\lt \frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{b+c}$,so all is left is to show that $a+b\lt \frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{b+c}$, I've tried to make use of the fact that $\frac{1}{c}\gt \frac{1}{a+b}$, to try and show that $\frac{1}{c}\lt \frac{1}{a+c}+\frac{1}{b+c}$, but I wasn't able to do that, so any help or easier approach are much appreciated.

The inequality is obviously wrong. When $a$ and $b$ and therefore $a+b$ are arbitrarily large, the right-hand side vanishes.

Oops sorry that was a typo, I'll correct it right away

Could you please add how you showed the left inequality? Also, there are still some typos in the body of the post.

Ok, I'll add it

$\frac 1c < \frac{1}{a+c} + \frac{1}{b+c}$ is not a consequence: $a=b=3, c=1$.

I see, so my approach wasn't quite the most convenient. Any suggestions?

Why would $ \frac{a+b} { ( a+c)(b+c) } < a+b$? It is true only if $ (a+c)(b+c) > 1$, so are you assuming that (say) these positive reals are also integers? $\quad$ And because of that error, (most of) the rest of your statements no longer apply.

Here's one possible approach: Show that $ \frac{1}{a+c} + \frac{1}{b+c}$ is minimal when $c$ is maximal, so it suffices to  show that $ \frac{ 1}{ a+b} < \frac{1}{2a+b} + \frac{1}{2b+a} $.  Do something similar for the other side.

For the left inequality, we proceed as follows. First, we have
$$
\left|\frac{1}{a+c} - \frac{1}{b+c}\right| = \frac{|a-b|}{(a+c)(b+c)} < \frac{c}{(a+c)(b+c)} < \frac1{a+b},
$$
where the last inequality follows from
$$
c(a+b) = ca + cb < ca + cb + ab + c^2 = (a+c)(b+c).
$$

For the right inequality, we proceed as follows. First, we have
\begin{align}
&(a+c)(b+c) - (a+b)(b+c) - (a+b)(a+c)
\\
&= c^2 - b^2 - a^2 - ab - bc - ac
\\
&= c(c-a-b) - a^2 - b^2 - ab
\\
&< 0.
\end{align}
Dividing both sides by $(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)$ gives the right inequality.
